# What is the correct $\det(A^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse, matrix-equations

[image]

Ok so I think I know why this is incorrect, because of the following:

$$\det\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}\neq \frac{ad-bc}{ad-bc}$$

However, by adding a *det* in the middle it would be correct:
$$\det(\frac{1}{ad-bc}det(\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}))= \frac{ad-bc}{ad-bc}$$
And thus:
$$\det\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{d}{(ad-bc)} & \frac{-b}{(ad-bc)}\\ 
\frac{-c}{(ad-bc)} & \frac{a}{(ad-bc)}
\end{bmatrix}$$

However the answer is:

[image]

I do not understand the *divides twice by $ad-bc$* bit, is there a rule I've misinterpreted somewhere?

**Answer, I just want to be clear for others having trouble:**

$$\det\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}=\left ( \frac{1}{ad-bc} \right )^{2}det\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\ 
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}=\left ( \frac{1}{(ad-bc)^{2}} \right )(ad-bc)=\frac{ad-bc}{(ad-bc)^{2}}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply a constant $c$ to a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, the determinant is multiplied by $c^n$, i.e.

$$ \det(cA) = c^n \det(A) $$

Now $c = \frac{1}{ad - bc}$ and $n = 2$. The result follows directly.

Comment: Ah, so the constant in this case is $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$. Ok gotcha.

Comment: Could you double check the calculation under my question to see if it is correct?

Comment: It looks good. :)

Comment: Ok feelin' goood! Thanks again!